# foreach only adds 1 row to table

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am using the opencart system and I've added a specific form for our company. Basically it keeps up with our orders as we input into the system. I'm trying to add to multiple records to a table, but it only will work for the first one.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_orders SET customer = '" . $data['customer'] . "', email = '" . $data['email'] . "', telephone = '" . $data['telephone'] . "', purchase_order = '" . $data['purchase_order'] . "', date_received = '" . $date . "', date_due = '" . $data['date_due'] . "', insurance = '" . $data['insurance'] . "'");

$customer_order = $this->db->getLastId();

foreach ($data['description'] as $description) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_order_description SET customer_order_id = '" . $customer_order . "', description = '" . $description . "'");
}
```

This item would have 2 descriptions, so it should place each description in the order description table, but it only does the first one.

Comment: $data['description'] can not have more than one value because this is a element of an array and not array.

Comment: @Basti, I don't know much about the specific system opencart. However there is nothing keeping `data['description']` from holding an array. Could use some more code in order to see how `$data` is populated.

Comment: This is the input for description with the form.    <textarea name="description[]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_description; ?>" rows="5" id="input-description" class="form-control" style="resize: none"></textarea>

Comment: @DanielSetréus: Sorry for my wrong answer, I deleted it.

Comment: Once again - `var_dump($data)`;

Comment: $data['description'] is an array. I used to count to see how many elements are in it, and it shows 2.

Comment: @BrentBarton Could you do a `var_dump($data)` just prior to the `foreach` and update the question with what's printed?

Comment: You want to get the lines of this textarea as array, right?

Comment: This is the var_dump              array(16) { ["customer"]=> string(9) "Worldwide" ["description"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "test1" [1]=> string(5) "test2" } }

Comment: Is customer_order_id a primary key?

Comment: I'd try and figure out if the query returns any error. As suggested by Basti there might be something else that creates the problem. Look here: http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=method_db_query. Seems like you could do `$insert = $this->db->query("INSERT ..."); var_dump($insert)`. `$insert` should be boolean true if the query is successful.